# CakePHP + AngularJS + complex json output

Tags: cakephp, angularjs

I have complex JSON output.

```
{"pages":[{"Page":{"id":"1","title":"My title"}}]}
```

How can I use it in view with angularjs foreach cycle?

Thank You.

Edit:
Somebody had written a tip, but deleted it:) thank you.

I solved it this way

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="page in pages.pages"><a href="p/{{page.Page.id}}-{{page.Page.title}}">{{page.Page.title}}</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4):

I mean you almost have it right (?)

On the client:

```
function PagesController($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('pages/index.json').success(function(data) {
        $scope.pages = data.pages;
    });
}
```

Within the view file:

```
<ul ng-controller="PagesController">
    <li ng-repeat="obj in pages"><a>{{obj.Page.title}}</a></li>
</ul>
```

If you don't support the .json extension then just get it where ever you have it.

Answer (score 3):

You can take look at this [Format Associative JSON to Work With Knockout.js](http://mindthecode.com/format-associative-json-to-work-with-knockout-js/)

Hope it helps